# Fazer div aparecer é sumir após um tempo

Tags: javascript, html, css

Tenho uma um código que gera um numero aleatório é aparecer na div = valor, logo em seguida. Mais eu queria que essa div fica-se invisível e apos eu clickar no botão ela aparece fala-se o valor e sumi-se logo em seguida. Alguém sabe como se cria isso?

```
<html>

<body bgcolor="black"></body>

<script>

    function rollDice() {
    var roll = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20) + 1;
    valor.innerHTML = roll;
    }

</script>

<input type="button" value="Click" id="clickbutton" onclick="rollDice()">

<div id="valor" class="dice">00</div>

<style>

@import url('http://fonts.cdnfonts.com/css/cmu-typewriter-text');

#valor {
        font-family:'CMU Typewriter Text', sans-serif;
        font-size: 60px;
        border: none;
        border-bottom:1px solid Grey;
        color: White;
        position: absolute;
        top: 1%;
        left: 1%;

    }

#clickbutton {
    position: absolute;
    top: 7%;
    left: 7%;
}
</style>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Olá, você pode usar o `setTimeout()` do `javascript` mesmo, dentro da sua função `rollDice()` com um tempo de 3 segundos iria mostrar, logo após você removeria com `css` a div, se não fui muito claro é só falar, espero que ajude. O exemplo ficaria assim:

```js
function rollDice() {
      var contentdiv = document.getElementById('valor');
      // seu código... Math.floor(Math.random() * 20) + 1;
      
      setTimeout(() => {
         contentdiv.style.display = 'none';
      },3000);
   }
```

Comment: mais ainda tem um problema, quando o valor some ele some pra sempre, quando clicka novamente no input o valor não parece mais, tem como resolver?